# Hibernate - Mapping issues

Tags: hibernate

Im hitting an issue with a hibernate mapping,

My database has been designed to ba a One to Many.

**One** *Course/Teacher/Student*, can have **Many** *Registers*

Pretty much all entity classes are the same relation, 
[image]

So if we take a **Student** as a example, this will be my Mapping

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity //here you define your class as entity which means is connected to the database 
@Table(name="students") //here you are referring the SQL table 

public class Student {
    @Id //to define it is a primary key
    @Column(name="student_id")  // name must be exact as the column in SQL
    private String studentID;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName; 

    @Column(name="date_of_birth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    //Establishing Mapping 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="student_id",
               cascade=CascadeType.ALL,targetEntity = Student.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     List <Register> registers;
```

And that will be **Register** Class which will be Entity for *Registration* table.

```
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity //here you define your class as entity which means is connected to the database 
@Table(name="REGISTRATION") //here you are referring the SQL table

public class Register {

    @Column(name="course_id")
    String course_id;

    @Column(name="course_name")
    String course_name;

    @Column(name="schedule")
    String schedule;

    @Id
    @Column(name="student_id")
    String student_id;

    @Column(name="employee_id")
    String employee_id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH.MERGE.PERSIST.REFRESH.REMOVE,targetEntity = Course.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="students",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="student_id"))
    Student student;


    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH.MERGE.PERSIST.REFRESH.REMOVE,targetEntity = Course.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="courses",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"))
    Course course;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH.MERGE.PERSIST.REFRESH.REMOVE,targetEntity = Course.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="teacher",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"))
    Teacher teacher;
```

And My output is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on model.Register.course references an unknown entity: model.Course
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:97)
```

Any kind of help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What about `model.Course`, do you have this entity?

Comment: Check for targetEntity = Course.class for Student and Teacher. I think should be Student.class for student and Teacher.class for Teacher